# Need help identifying the manufacturer of a frost free anti-siphon faucet.

Tags: faucet

Need help identifying the manufacturer of a frost free anti-siphon faucet.  Want to replace the 4" spring loaded stem assembly, but can't find the part.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the frost free anti-siphon hose bib at a local plumbing supply store.  It only cost about $20.  I will rob the stem assembly from the new hose bib and insert it into the old (still good) hose bib.  Will save time and money from cutting a hole in my wall to get to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Proflow frostfree antisiphon silcock. Check Fergusons website I had same one took forever to find .

Comment: That helped me find it. Ferguson has a repair kit for this PF73AS valve. The part number on their website is PF73ARK2 and it's called "PROFLO Repair Kit for PF73AS Series Wall Hydrants".