# Need help identifying non-frost outdoor faucet

Tags: outdoorfaucet

I just need help to identify this outdoor frost-free faucet so I can replace its vacuum breaker.

[image]

Comment: The "ASSE 1019" is a standard that it meets... it's not a model #

Comment: Google "Frost Proof Sillcock Stems" and match it to yours.

Comment: Thanks would you happen  to know where I cam locate the model number?

Comment: See here https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141060/need-help-identifying-the-manufacturer-of-a-frost-free-anti-siphon-faucet

Comment: You will have to take it out to find out.

Comment: Do I take  out the valve inside  from the front of the faucet or take out out from the connection that goes to main water line ??

Comment: see you pic number 3, there you unscrew it

Comment: It might be easier to just replace the whole faucet than trying to find individual parts that fit.

Comment: The vacuum breakers seem to frequently be interchangeable, based on looking up a part for a previous question regarding a broken one. Head on down to the hardware store and pick up a frost-free sillcock vacuum breaker repair/replacement kit and odds are good that it will fit, without stressing about the brand. Depending what's leaking, a simple o-ring replacement might be all you need (I note the vacuum breaker is cropped out of these photos...)

Comment: Ecnerwal: thanks for reaching  out it  is the vacuum seal it broke and I ordered  one on Amazon  looked good and all but the size is like a hair or 2 bigger  so I went to the ace hardware store but they didn't have just the vacuum breaker  they had the whole  part it about 30 bucks probably  just going to replace  it I didn't want to break the wall but I did already  so probably  best thing  todo now is just replace  the whole thing  appreciate  everyone's help

Comment: gnicko: thanks for reaching  out I think you are right thanks for the suggestion I think that will save me a few headaches

Comment: Ruskes:took it apart completely but still didn't see any brand appreciate the help